nginx angular ssr route changes not working
I have a problem with nginx and angular ssr. For example, my website has a route that is parent_path/dynamic_path/child_path, now I want the client on the website to see dynamic_path.mydomain.com/child_path and have nginx take care of transforming that, now I can do this but when I enter dynamic_path. mydomain.com/child_route gives me an error that the routes do not match but on the front server the route is correct, I understand that my front is verifying the client's route and not the server's because when I enter dynamic_route.mydomain. com/path_child tells me that the path path_child does not match.
